# How to get the highest scorer among all the users in game center?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center

I want to get the the highest scorer from the game center. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link to the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) on using Game Center.  Part way down is a section on getting Leadership scores.  That should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot and here is the exact link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW10